# Hit rate limitation in nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, robots.txt

Is it possible to limit the hit rate/IP address in nutch? In other words, can I configure nutch so that it will only hit an IP x number of times per hour, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can limit rate by changing fetcher.server.delay, fetcher.server.min.delay, fetcher.threads.per.queue, fetcher.queue.mode settings values in nutch-default.xml file.